# Dropping databse if it exists, is it correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

I had uploaded an assignment that uses a database with sql.

We go through localhost/phpadmin and I'm using xampp. He told me my sql file failed to load and I need to reupload it. He also said "The first line in your script should be to drop your database if it exists. This will allow you to test your script and your code to make sure everything works together." When I tested it before it all worked together fine so I'm a little confused.

I'm wanting to make sure I have the right idea in my code of what needs to be done. The line where I drop the database, is this the right way to do what he is asking? Or is there a better way or more to what is needed?

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='richard_ricardo_assignment_db')
DROP DATABASE richard_ricardo_assignment_db

CREATE DATABASE richard_ricardo_assignment_db;

CREATE USER 'richardweb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'richardchocolate';
/*GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON *.* TO 'richardweb'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;*/
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `richard\_ricardo\_assignment\_db`.* TO 'richardweb'@'localhost';

/*GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, FILE ON richard_ricardo_assignment_db.* TO 'richardweb'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;*/
CREATE table Student (
 studentID int,
 name varchar(255),
 email varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (studentID)
);

INSERT INTO Student (studentID, name, email)

VALUES (1, "Po Black", "poblack@gmail.com"),(2, "Shifu Hoffman", "shifuhoffman@gmail.com"),(3, "Tigress Jolie", "tigressjolie@gmail.com"),(4, "Jennifer Yuh", "jenniferyuh@gmail.com"),
(5, "Ox Storming", "oxstorming@gmail.com"),(6, "Monkey Chan", "monkeychan@gmail.com"),(7, "Viper Liu", "viperliu@gmail.com"),(8, "Mantis Rogen", "mantisrogen@gmail.com"),
(9, "Crane Cross", "cranecross@gmail.com"),(10, "Oogway Kim", "oogwaykim@gmail.com"),(11, "Ping Hong", "pinghong@gmail.com");
```

Comment: @Shadow you marked as duplicate too early, the referenced duplicate is not the best answer to this question

Comment: A lot of information in your query seems hardcoded to your database, USE is used to specify the database to be used for that query, in this case you are actually creating a database so you don't need it. select * from sys.databases will not work on phpmyadmin since it uses information_schema database to store database information. I also don't think He will appreciate you creating yourself as a user and granting permissions.

Comment: replace your first 3 lines with -  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `richard_ricardo_assignment_db`;

Comment: @comphonia I disagree, it provides exactly the answer the OP is looking for, which was also provided here by someone else and by yourself.

Comment: @Shadow **was** being the operative word. Thanks for posting the duplicate.

Comment: @Nick wow, this is the first time that sy, who answered a question I marked as duplicate, thanks me for the duplicate!

Comment: @Shadow I try to flag dupes as much as I can, sometimes I can't easily find them so I post an answer and wait for someone else to do it. It doesn't worry me if the question gets deleted later.